# Ember setupController fires observes, how can i prevent that

Tags: ember.js

My code looks something like this

```
App.ItemRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    var model = this.modelFor('item');
    controller.setProperties({
      name : model.get('name'),
      title: model.get('title')
    });
  }
});

App.ItemController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  saveOnChange: function() {
    console.log('saveOnChange');
  }.observes('name', 'title'),
});
```

From my understanding because i am using `setProperties` the observe should only fire once , but it fire two times

also wrapping the `setProperties` with `beginPropertyChanges` & `endPropertyChanges` still fires twice

---

what i ultimately is for it to not fire at all, so what i ended up doing was changing the controller code to be like this

```
App.ItemController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  load: false,
  saveOnChange: function() {
    if(!this.get('load')) {
      this.set('load', true);
      return;
    }
    console.log('saveOnChange');
  }.observes('name', 'title'),
});
```

this code would work if the change is only fired once, but it won't work if its fired multiple times (that's my case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setProperties` function doesn't coalesce your observers (unfortunately there's no way to do that), it just groups them into one operation. The source might help you to better see what it does:

```
Ember.setProperties = function(self, hash) {
  changeProperties(function() {
    for(var prop in hash) {
      if (hash.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { set(self, prop, hash[prop]); }
    }
  });
  return self;
};
```

So, back to your problem. The best way that I can think of is to debounce your function.

```
App.ItemController = Em.ObjecController.extend({

    load: false,

    saveOnChange: function() {
        Em.run(this, 'debouncedSave', 150);
    }.observes('name', 'title'),

    debouncedSave: function() {
        if(!this.get('load')) {
            this.set('load', true);
        }
    }

 });
```

If you're not familiar with debouncing, you can read about it [here](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function). There are probably some other solutions involving direct manipulation of the properties, but I'm not sure if that's a road you want to go down.

Comment: i used `Em.run.once` & it worked, ty for the direction